# Why don't I get a value from drupal_static()?

Tags: 7

This post is basically a duplicate question of one I asked a little while back: [Using Static Variables in a Custom Module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85968/using-static-variables-in-a-custom-module). Unfortunately I can't get my own solution to work.

I'm trying to use a static variable in a custom module.

```
function tellafriend_userfullname_function() {
  global $user;
  $var = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__);

  if (!isset($var)) {
    // generate contents of static variable
    $var = user_load($user->uid);
  }

  return $var;
}
```

The static variable will be used in the form submission handler and in `hook_mail()`.

```
function tellafriend_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $var = &drupal_static('tellafriend_userfullname_function');
  $params = array();

  if ($form_state['values']['cv_included'] == '1') {
    $params['1'] =  array('uri' => $var->field_cv_upload['und']['0']['uri'], 'filename' => $var->field_cv_upload['und']['0']['filename'],);
  };

  // Other email set-up goes here.

  $message = drupal_mail('tellafriend', 'notify', $email, language_default(), $params);
}

function tellafriend_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
   $message['headers']['MIME-Version'] = '1.0';
   $message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/mixed;';
   $message['body'][] = $var->field_full_name['und']['0']['safe_value'];
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: How/where are you invoking the call to `tellafriend_userfullname_function()`, does it happen before the form function is used?

Comment: Yep before the form function and after hook_block_view.

Comment: If `tellafriend_userfullname_function()` is not a hook, why aren't you simply calling it, instead of using `drupal_static('tellafriend_userfullname_function')`?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Probably my fault, I tried to explain statics in the OP's previous question and the point got a bit muddied as we were going back and forth over various concepts

Comment: @Clive Your suggestion of using `drupal_static()` is perfectly fine, considering the previous question's context. After all, the previous question doesn't explain which function is going to use the value stored with `drupal_static()`. For what we know, it could be the case of two different hooks needing the same value; in that case I would suggest of using `drupal_static()` as you did.

Comment: @kiamlaluno The current question does have two different hooks needing the same value, `hook_form_submit` and `hook_mail`. But I couldn't get the answer I'd used to previously to work and I was worried I'd put an incorrect answer in the previous question.

Comment: `hook_form_submit()` is not a hook Drupal uses; what you are showing is a form submission handler, which is a normal function, not a hook. Then, you didn't speak of `hook_mail()` in your original question.

Comment: Aah whoops, inexperience :( Hook_mail wasn't in the original question it's only relevant here. My worry was the answer I'd left on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85968/using-static-variables-in-a-custom-module was incorrect (and would mis-inform) as I couldn't get it to work a second time. In theory is the code I've posted correct? If so then I'll leave my original post as is otherwise I need to correct it.

Comment: Still, you don't show the code that is calling `tellafriend_userfullname_function()`. If that function is not called, your code doesn't work.

Comment: Aah brilliant cheers! I thought `$var =  &drupal_static('tellafriend_userfullname_function');` would do the initialize and I wouldn't need to call the function by itself. I've updated the first question with all the info from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to call `drupal_static()` directly? You have a getter function `tellafriend_userfullname_function()`. This function takes care of your cache and handles it.

```
function tellafriend_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $var =  tellafriend_userfullname_function();
}
```

Furthermore, you don't even need to cache a `user_load()` call with `drupal_static()`. The entity cache takes care of it. So your construct is counter-performat.

So why not go the easy way?

```
function tellafriend_form($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  $var =  user_load($user->id);
}
```

Comment: Both are good points. Didn't know about entity_cache so I was worried about making multiple user_loads for the same item. But yep easy way is good way. Thank you very much. I'll leave this question open for a bit, just in case anyone knows why the static variable doesn't work. (i.e. someone else who has to use static variables finds this)

Comment: I've copied your answer and put it into http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85968/using-static-variables-in-a-custom-module/86035#86035, because this one was a duplicate. Is that ok?

Answer (score 4):

The default value returned by [drupal_static()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7) is `NULL`; this means that, when you call the function passing for `$name` a value that has not been used from another function, the value associated with that name is `NULL`, or the second argument passed to `drupal_static()`.

In your case, you need to call `tellafriend_userfullname_function()` twice: once to initialize the static value, and once to get the static value.

```
function tellafriend_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $var = tellafriend_userfullname_function();
  $params = array();

  if ($form_state['values']['cv_included'] == '1') {
     $params['1'] = array('uri' => $var->field_cv_upload['und']['0']['uri'], 'filename' => $var->field_cv_upload['und']['0']['filename'],);
  };

  // Other email set-up goes here.

  $message = drupal_mail('tellafriend', 'notify', $email, language_default(), $params);
}

function tellafriend_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  $var = tellafriend_userfullname_function();

  $message['headers']['MIME-Version'] = '1.0';
  $message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/mixed;';
  $message['body'][] = $var->field_full_name['und']['0']['safe_value'];
}
```

In this case, I would not use `drupal_static()`, for two reasons.

- The value you set and get from `drupal_static()` is a value you can get from a global variable
- Even if that would not be the case, you could simply use a static variable inside `tellafriend_userfullname_function()`, since `drupal_static()` is used for a static value that needs to be reset externally from the function that defines it

If you look at the code of [drupal_bootstrap()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7), you will notice the following comments.

```
  // Not drupal_static(), because the only legitimate API to control this is to
  // call drupal_bootstrap() with a new phase parameter.
  static $final_phase;
  // Not drupal_static(), because it's impossible to roll back to an earlier
  // bootstrap state.
  static $stored_phase = -1;
```

`drupal_static()` is not a replacement for every static variable that could be used from a function; it should be used when the static variable is used to save a state another function could need to reset. The documentation for `drupal_static()` says:

> A guideline is that if a function's static variable does not depend on any information outside of the function that might change during a single page request, then it's ok to use the "static" keyword instead of the `drupal_static()` function.

As example of when `drupal_static()` is used, see [`menu_reset_static_cache()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_reset_static_cache/7), which contains the following code.

```
  drupal_static_reset('_menu_build_tree');
  drupal_static_reset('menu_tree');
  drupal_static_reset('menu_tree_all_data');
  drupal_static_reset('menu_tree_page_data');
  drupal_static_reset('menu_load_all');
  drupal_static_reset('menu_link_get_preferred');
```

If [`menu_tree()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree/7) didn't use `drupal_static()`, resetting the static variable it uses would not be possible, if not changing the function to use the following code.

```
function menu_tree($menu_name = NULL, $reset = FALSE) {
  static $menu_output = array();

  if ($reset) {
    $menu_output = array();
  }

  if (isset($menu_name)) {
    if (!isset($menu_output[$menu_name])) {
      $tree = menu_tree_page_data($menu_name);
      $menu_output[$menu_name] = menu_tree_output($tree);
    }
  }

  return $menu_output[$menu_name];
}
```

This would have been possible, but it would have changed the interface between the function and the functions using it. Since this is a common pattern among different Drupal functions, defining `drupal_static()` and using it in those functions needing it has been a Smart Thing™.

Comment: Good info re: `drupal_static()` vs `static` keyword.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to explain that. When you talk about the  global variable do you mean `$user`? I don't think you can get the value needed from `$user` as it doesn't load custom account fields (i.e. `field_full_name` and `field_cv_upload` in this case)

Comment: @DominicWoodman You can use `$GLOBALS['user']` in every function where you need the value; there isn't any need of a function that stores in a static variable a value derived from a global variable. Then, you don't need even a global variable, but call [user_uid_optional_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_uid_optional_load/7) without passing any argument to the function. Since the currently logged-in user doesn't change during a page load, there is no need to save the user object in a static variable.